# Safely kill background process started in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

Imagine I start a background process in a bash script, in this case `http-server` and I'd like to kill it when the script exits. I might do this like so:

```sh
# launch http-server in the background
http-server -p8080 &

# capture PID of background process
HTTP_PID=$!

trap "kill $HTTP_PID" EXIT 

# ... more stuff
```

That seems to be the recommended way to capture the PID of a background process, but there's a problem: if the process fails to start or fails at any point later, the PID may be recycled and used by another process, in which case my `kill` will kill some random process on the system.

How can I safely kill *only* the process that started in this script, doing nothing if the process already died?

Answer (score 1):

This should achieve what you expected :

```
trap "pkill --parent $$ http-server" EXIT
```

To kill a particular pid :

```
function killpid {
    local ppid=$1 pid=$2 cmd=$3
    local v_pid="$(ps -h --ppid $ppid -o pid,cmd | awk -v pid=$pid -v cmd="$cmd" '$1 == pid && $2 == cmd {print pid}')"
    if  test -n "$v_pid"; then
        echo "Killing $v_pid..."
        kill $v_pid
    fi
}

sleep 2 &
echo "Spawning $!"
sleep 2 &
echo "Spawning $!"
trap "killpid $$ $! sleep" EXIT
```

Substitute `http-server` for `sleep` after testing.

Comment: Hmm, nice approach. Perhaps slightly safer with `--exact`. It's a shame there is no `--pid` option to `pkill` since this doesn't let me target a _specific_ instance of `http-server` that I launched, although in this case I'm launching only one.

Comment: ‘ps’ has both—pid and —ppid, with those you should be able to verify when you actually kill a particular process id